# PHP Find all possible date combinations within interval

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two dates which is event start date and end date, in my php script I want to find out all the possible combination of dates between the two dates

I mean i want to find out all possible days a participant come for an event,

assume start date in20/10/2014 and end date is23/10/2014,

all possible combinations are

1. 20/10/2014 -23/10/2014
2. 20/10/2014 -22/10/2014
3. 20/10/2014 -21/10/2014
4. 21/10/2014 -23/10/2014
5. 21/10/2014 -22/10/2014
6. 22/10/2014 -23/10/2014
7. 20/10/2014 -21/10/2014- 22/10/2014
8. 20/10/2014 -21/10/2014- 22/10/2014 -23/10/2014
9. 21/10/2014 -22/10/2014 -23/10/2014

The reason I want to find out all possible combination is, i have different discount option based on event participants day sessions.

Comment: You should use different column for `start date` and `end date` in your table

Comment: show us what you already did

Comment: What's wrong with simple check box: day 1, day 2, etc.? What about single day participation? Or for example 20/10/2014 and 23/10/2014 (skip a day or two)?

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be broken down in two parts:

1. For any two dates, create an array with all the days that fall within the date interval.
2. Create all possible combinations of all possible numbers of days (from 1 to n, where n == the number of days within the interval).

For the first part, I will use the [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) PHP class, and for the second the [Math_Combinatorics](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics) PEAR package. Here is the full code:

```
require_once 'Math/Combinatorics.php';

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$format = "d/m/Y";
$start  = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, "20/10/2014");
$end    = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, "23/10/2014");

$period = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

$dates = array();
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $dates[] = $date->format($format);
}

$dates[] = $end->format($format);

$combinations  = array();
$combinatorics = new Math_Combinatorics();

foreach (range(1, count($dates)) as $number_of_combinations) {
    foreach ($combinatorics->combinations($dates, $number_of_combinations) as $combination) {
        $combinations[] = $combination;
    }
}

print_r($combinations);
```

The result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20/10/2014
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21/10/2014
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22/10/2014
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23/10/2014
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20/10/2014
            [1] => 21/10/2014
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20/10/2014
            [2] => 22/10/2014
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20/10/2014
            [3] => 23/10/2014
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [1] => 21/10/2014
            [2] => 22/10/2014
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [1] => 21/10/2014
            [3] => 23/10/2014
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [2] => 22/10/2014
            [3] => 23/10/2014
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20/10/2014
            [1] => 21/10/2014
            [2] => 22/10/2014
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20/10/2014
            [1] => 21/10/2014
            [3] => 23/10/2014
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20/10/2014
            [2] => 22/10/2014
            [3] => 23/10/2014
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [1] => 21/10/2014
            [2] => 22/10/2014
            [3] => 23/10/2014
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20/10/2014
            [1] => 21/10/2014
            [2] => 22/10/2014
            [3] => 23/10/2014
        )

)
```